# Filtering VUE rendered data with JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering, server-side-rendering

I just started a new project with VueJS as frontend and CakePHP as backend. My "developer" days go back in time quite a bit, so I am right now pretty lost with the variety of frameworks and technologies (choosing and understanding).

Going to the point, from the frontend VUE I get a JSON, and I then iterate with v-for inside a table. This table uses List.js to perform some ordering.

HTML code:

```
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-nowrap card-table">
       <thead>
         <tr>
          <th><a class="list-sort text-muted" data-sort="item-name" href="#">Nombre</a></th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="list font-size-base" id="userList">
         <tr v-for="userItem in userAll">
           <td><span class="item-name">{{ userItem.username }}</span></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Vue:

```
      el: "#userList",
      data: function () {
        return {
          userAll: []
        }
      },
      beforeMount(){
        this.getUsers();
      },
      methods: {
        async getUsers(){
          const res = await fetch('http://localhost/users/index.json');
          const salida = await res.json();
          this.userAll = salida;
        }
      }
    });
```

The code works (i.e. the list of users is correctly displayed in the table), but I can't get the table order functionality to work. I know now that the List.js just sees "{{ userItem.user_department }}" and not the values that the user sees (sorry for not being too technically accurate).

I can probably use the native Vue filtering capabilities, but I am afraid this will happen again with some other JS plugins/components that I won't be able to replace so easily with Vue. Is there a simpler way to make this working without discarding all the JS functionality? (I am fairly lost, but I don't know if SSR could be a cleaner solution, or I am just pointing to the wrong direction).

Thank you.

Edited: I add the full table.

Comment: what is list.js? where are these table headers? why is a theme developer involved?

Comment: I asked the theme developer and she told me that she uses List.js to perform ordering. Just before the previous code:

`<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><a class="list-sort text-muted" data-sort="item-name" href="#">Nombre</a></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
`
When used with static html, it does indeed work. But when used with Vue mustache tags, all that the List.js sees is the Vue mustache tag, not the data dynamically got with the v-for.

Comment: I am using a third party theme because I want to ease the styling, to I can focus on learning Vue and CakePHP.

Comment: List.js comes from listjs.com. It's vanilla javascript adding order capabilities. The table looks like this:

`<table class="table table-sm table-hover table-nowrap card-table">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th><a class="list-sort text-muted" data-sort="item-name" href="#">Nombre</a></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="list font-size-base" id="userList">
 <tr v-for="userItem in userAll">
 <td><span class="item-name">{{ userItem.username }}</span></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>`